# A question about syntax in inheritance of exceptions

Tags: c++, inheritance, exception

I have the following class that represents a stack.

```
template <class T>
class stack {
    ...
public:
    explicit stack(int max_size = 100);
    stack(const Stack& s);
    ~stack();
    stack& operator=(const Stack&);
    void push(const T& t);
    void pop();
    T& top();
    const T& top() const;
    int getSize() const;
    class Exception : public std::exception {};
    class Full : public Exception {};
    class Empty : public Exception {};
};
```

Now, I have a second class that inherits from stack. It is similar but it has a special method called `popConditional`that pops elements out of the stack until a generic condition is met by the top element of the stack.

If there is no such element, I am supposed to throw an exception from a class named `NotFound`that inherits from the class `Exception` defined in `Stack`. My question is what is the proper syntax:

```
template <class T>
class ConditionalStack : public Stack<T> {
public:
    class NotFound : public Exception {
        const char* what() const override { return "not found"; }
    };
};
```

Or

```
template <class T>
class ConditionalStack : public Stack<T> {
public:
    class NotFound : public Stack<T>::Exception {
        const char* what() const override { return "not found"; }
    };
};
```

If the first one is not correct, why is that the case? Shouldn't the class `Exception` be inherited as well?

Comment: Both of them are correct. `ConditionalStack` has visibility for `Exception`. The second one is probably "safer".

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve].  The code you provided would not compile, since you've intermixed use of `stack` and `Stack`.    THe second form is what you want, since `Exception` is a dependent name (depends on the template parameter `T`).     Except that you have left off the `noexcept` qualifier for `what()` (required C++11 and later) and therefore made the throw specification looser.

Answer (score 2):

As `Exception` is a dependent name, you should use second snippet.